# AD - memberOf attribute missing on some accounts

Tags: active-directory, ldapsearch

On my AD domain some users do not have "memberOf" attribute set, so these accounts do not appear in search results when I perform an LDAP query like this:

`memberOf=CN=Group_A,OU=G-Security,OU=CB-Groups,OU=company,DC=lan,DC=name,DC=it`

Performing that search gives me a partial list of Group_A members, only the ones with "memberOf" attribute populated.
But if I browse Group_A with AD Users and Computers I can correctly see all members, and if I perform and LDAP search on Group_A I correctly receive all members in "members" attribute.

Reading the docs I found that "memberOf" is a calculated attribute, so I cannot edit it, but is there a way to re-calculate it? Or is there something wrong in the accounts that do not have "memberOf" attribute?

I am trying to have that LDAP query search working because it is used by an external application to retrieve the list of users enabled to use it.

Comment: Are all of your domain controllers GCs? And which DC is the infrastructure master?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not administer directly the AD environment, but I will ask to my AD administrator. Should I try to query the infrastructure master server?

Comment: The `memberOf` attribute does not exist for the primary group of the user.

Comment: Generally an LDAP-aware product will have a way to supply a group DN directly rather than calculating its membership via a per-user "memberof" property. I'd check the vendor documentation.